# Client server programming in java with options to user

Tags: java, sockets, client

My task is to display three options to the user 1)connect to server 2)post data 3)disconnect. I am having trouble in sending the file to the server. "The file needs to be sent from client to server". I am new to socket programming and however I try the connection is being reset while I try to send the file to server.

server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Server extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port "
                        + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(server.getInputStream());
                File file = new File("compile.txt");
                BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                        file));
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    String str = reader.next();
                    fileWriter.write(str);
                    System.out.println("" + str);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 4444;
        try {
            Thread t = new Server(port);
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

client

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket client = null;
        boolean flag = true;

        while (flag) {
            System.out
                    .println("Please enter your choice\n1.Connect to Server\n2.Post Data\n3.Disconnect from Server");
            Scanner userChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = userChoice.nextInt();
            String serverName = "localhost";
            int port = 4444;
            if (choice == 1) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                            + " on port " + port);
                    client = new Socket(serverName, port);
                    System.out.println("Just connected to "
                            + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (choice == 2) {

                System.out.println("enter path of file to be compiled");
                Scanner pathReader = new Scanner(System.in);
                String path = pathReader.next();
                pathReader.close();
                String line;
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                                client.getOutputStream(), true);
                        writer.write(line);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    client.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (choice == 3) {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else
                System.out.println("enter a valid input");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all client-server socket connections and applications are pretty complicated. I'd recommend reading: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#sockets

couple of things to consider:

- make sure there is nothing running on the socket.
- make sure that the server is listening
- You are running the server on one thread, so if it finishes at all then it won't restart
- You are not closing the fileWriter once you have finished writing -

please post your output/any stacktraces you have

Comment: yes the server is running i assigned it to port 4444